# Pandas DataFrame table's styling in Django view

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-templates, django-pandas

In a Django application I create a DataFrame, later on I transform it to html and pass to the view

```
table = df.to_html(index=False)
return render(request, 'results.html',{'table': table})
```

In results.html I add that table

```
{{ table|safe }}
```

And I get this table.
[Table in Django's view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAK2w.png). Is there a way to add styling to it in the template? I would like to add some spacing between text and borders, as well as making titles for the columns centered.

Comment: Just normal css?

Answer (score 0):

You can style the elements as normal with CSS.

```css
table {
    max-width: 50vw
    ....
}
```

Or style whichever elements you want to

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of a dataframe html you set it in the view file using the style attribute.

Here I'm using a standard bootstrap table which I import in my base.html file

Bootstrap docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Panda's Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_attributes.html

```
import pandas as pd

def table_view(request):
    df = """create dataframe from data"""

    table = df.style.set_table_attributes('class="table table-dark"')
    
    return render(request, 'results.html',{'table': table.to_html()})
```